# Include an / in my XML at the end of a line

Tags: powershell

I have an XML file that looks like this (there is alot more file tags in my file):

```xml
<file
  name="YYY/xxxx/xyz/zyx.cs"
  count = '15'>
  <severity level="0" count="4"/>
  <severity level="2" count="11"/>
  <source  name="ReviewLinqMethodRule" count="1"/>
  <source  name="AvoidRepetitiveCallsToPropertiesRule" count="3"/>
  <source  name="AvoidUnnecessarySpecializationRule" count="3"/>
  <source  name="CheckParametersNullityInVisibleMethodsRule" count="4"/>
  <source  name="PreferEmptyInstanceOverNullRule" count="2"/>
  <source  name="AvoidRepetitiveCastsRule" count="2"/>
</file>
```

I would like a PowerShell code that searches through the whole file and every time it finds `name=`, the link should be changed to exactly the same except it should be added a `/` to the end.
so this

```
name="YYY/xxxx/xyz/zyx.cs"
```

should be changed to this

```
name="YYY/xxxx/xyz/zyx.cs"
```

So the above would look like this:

```xml
<file
  name="YYY/xxxx/xyz/zyx.cs/"
  count = '15'>
  <severity level="0" count="4"/>
  <severity level="2" count="11"/>
  <source  name="ReviewLinqMethodRule" count="1"/>
  <source  name="AvoidRepetitiveCallsToPropertiesRule" count="3"/>
  <source  name="AvoidUnnecessarySpecializationRule" count="3"/>
  <source  name="CheckParametersNullityInVisibleMethodsRule" count="4"/>
  <source  name="PreferEmptyInstanceOverNullRule" count="2"/>
  <source  name="AvoidRepetitiveCastsRule" count="2"/>
</file>
```

It needs to go though the hole file and look for all `name=`. The link will never be the same.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have got so far so I can print out each element:

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content -Path violations.xml

foreach( $file in $XML.violations.type.file) 
{ 
Write-Host $file.name 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content -Path $file_path
$XML.file.name = $XML.file.name + "/"
# then you can save it on the same file with
$XML.Save($file_path)
```

After the OP's edit.
You should try to use `regex`, but here's crude solution:

```
$i = 0;
$xml = Get-Content -Path $file_path
foreach($line in $xml){
    if(($line -like "*name=*") -and ($line -like '*"*/*"*')){
       $temp += $line.Split('"')[0] + '"' + $line.Split('"')[1] + '/"'
    } else {
        $temp += $line
    }
    $i++
}
[xml]$xml = $temp
```